# sudo gem install cocoapods Erro cannot load such file -- socket

Tags: react-native

sudo gem install cocoapods Erro

ERROR: Loading command: install (LoadError)
cannot load such file -- socket
ERROR: While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
undefined method `invoke_with_build_args' for nil:NilClass

system macos 11.6（20G165)
xcode 13.0 (13A223)

Comment: rvm pkg install openssl
rvm reinstall ruby-2.1 --with-openssl-dir=$rvm_path/usr

is's OK

Comment: did you find any solution?